# How to fix my StoredProcedure to get records those are isActive=1 and plus also get records from same user if IsActive=0

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

In this stored procedure I am retrieving those recipes those are active and recipes by the logged in user even if the are not active but when i use search by category it still retrieves that recipe even if its category is different.
I want to get all recipes belonging to a category and if the recipe is added by the logged in user even if it is not active and belong to the category it should show other wise not.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[spRecipe_GetAll]
@userid int,
@RecipeName varchar(250),
@CategoryID int

as
begin
set nocount on;
IF (@RecipeName = '' and @CategoryID = 0)
    BEGIN
        SELECT distinct def_Recipes.ThumbImageUrl,
                        def_Category.CategoryName,
                        def_Recipes.RecipeID,
                        def_Recipes.Name,
                        def_Recipes.Description,
                        def_Recipes.RecipeFrom,
                        def_Recipes.RecipeYield,
                        def_Recipes.CookingTime,
                        def_Recipes.PrepTime,
                        def_Recipes.ReadyTime,      
                        def_Recipes.IsActive,
                        case when def_Recipes.IsActive =0 then 'DeActive' else 'Active' end  as isactive,
                        case when def_Recipes.IsApproved ='1' then 'Approved' when def_Recipes.IsApproved ='0' then 'Declined' else 'Pending' end  as IsApproved        

        FROM dbo.def_Recipes 
        INNER JOIN def_Category  ON def_Recipes.CategoryID = def_Category.CategoryID
        WHERE def_Recipes.IsActive='1'  OR userid=@userid and def_Recipes.IsActive='0'
    End

IF (@RecipeName != '' and @CategoryID = 0) 
    BEGIN
        SELECT distinct def_Recipes.ThumbImageUrl,
                        def_Category.CategoryName,
                        def_Recipes.RecipeID,
                        def_Recipes.Name,
                        def_Recipes.Description,
                        def_Recipes.RecipeFrom,
                        def_Recipes.RecipeYield,
                        def_Recipes.CookingTime,
                        def_Recipes.PrepTime,
                        def_Recipes.ReadyTime,
                        case when def_Recipes.IsActive =0 then 'DeActive' else 'Active' end  as isactive,
                        case when def_Recipes.IsApproved ='1' then 'Approved' when def_Recipes.IsApproved ='0' then 'Declined' else 'Pending' end  as IsApproved                

        FROM dbo.def_Recipes 
        INNER JOIN def_Category  ON def_Recipes.CategoryID = def_Category.CategoryID
        WHERE def_Recipes.Name = @RecipeName AND def_Recipes.IsActive='1' OR userid=@userid
    End 

    IF (@RecipeName = '' and @CategoryID > 0)
    BEGIN
        SELECT distinct def_Recipes.ThumbImageUrl,
                        def_Category.CategoryName,
                        def_Recipes.RecipeID,
                        def_Recipes.Name,
                        def_Recipes.Description,
                        def_Recipes.RecipeFrom,
                        def_Recipes.RecipeYield,
                        def_Recipes.CookingTime,
                        def_Recipes.PrepTime,
                        def_Recipes.ReadyTime,
                        case when def_Recipes.IsActive =0 then 'DeActive' else 'Active' end  as isactive,
                        case when def_Recipes.IsApproved ='1' then 'Approved' when def_Recipes.IsApproved ='0' then 'Declined' else 'Pending' end  as IsApproved                    

        FROM dbo.def_Recipes 
        INNER JOIN def_Category  ON def_Recipes.CategoryID = def_Category.CategoryID
        WHERE def_Recipes.CategoryID = @CategoryID AND def_Recipes.IsActive='1' OR userid=@userid 
    End
    IF (@RecipeName != '' and @CategoryID > 0)
    BEGIN
        SELECT distinct def_Recipes.ThumbImageUrl,
                        def_Category.CategoryName,
                        def_Recipes.RecipeID,
                        def_Recipes.Name,
                        def_Recipes.Description,
                        def_Recipes.RecipeFrom,
                        def_Recipes.RecipeYield,
                        def_Recipes.CookingTime,
                        def_Recipes.PrepTime,
                        def_Recipes.ReadyTime,
                        case when def_Recipes.IsActive =0 then 'DeActive' else 'Active' end  as isactive,
                        case when def_Recipes.IsApproved ='1' then 'Approved' when def_Recipes.IsApproved ='0' then 'Declined' else 'Pending' end  as IsApproved                    

        FROM dbo.def_Recipes 
        INNER JOIN def_Category  ON def_Recipes.CategoryID = def_Category.CategoryID
        WHERE def_Recipes.CategoryID = @CategoryID and def_Recipes.Name = @RecipeName AND def_Recipes.IsActive='1' OR userid=@userid
    End
```

end

Comment: Try changing your `WHERE` clause to this: `WHERE def_Recipes.IsActive='1'  OR (userid=@userid and def_Recipes.IsActive='0')`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can rewrite your procedure as shown below (it will full fill your condition as simple as well to understand). You don't need to repeat yourself for each if condition

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[spRecipe_GetAll]
@userid int,
@RecipeName varchar(250),
@CategoryID int

as
begin
set nocount on;
    SELECT distinct def_Recipes.ThumbImageUrl,
                        def_Category.CategoryName,
                        def_Recipes.RecipeID,
                        def_Recipes.Name,
                        def_Recipes.Description,
                        def_Recipes.RecipeFrom,
                        def_Recipes.RecipeYield,
                        def_Recipes.CookingTime,
                        def_Recipes.PrepTime,
                        def_Recipes.ReadyTime,      
                        def_Recipes.IsActive,
                        case when def_Recipes.IsActive =0 then 'DeActive' else 'Active' end  as isactive,
                        case when def_Recipes.IsApproved ='1' then 'Approved' when def_Recipes.IsApproved ='0' then 'Declined' else 'Pending' end  as IsApproved        

        FROM dbo.def_Recipes 
        INNER JOIN def_Category  ON def_Recipes.CategoryID = def_Category.CategoryID
        WHERE def_Recipes.IsActive='1'  OR userid=@userid and def_Recipes.IsActive='0'
        AND (ISNULL(@RecipeName='') ='' OR def_Recipes.Name = @RecipeName)
        AND (@CategoryID =0 OR  def_Recipes.CategoryID = @CategoryID )
    End
```